# Typescript get variable with current value during the program run

Tags: typescript

I've got a variable, getter and setter with the payload which I want to send. My payload has a param `${valueThatChanges}`

```
private _myPayload ='{
                    "rowCounts":{
                         "rowStart":1,
                         "rowLimit":5
                             },
                    "criteria":{
                         "${valueThatChanges}"
                            }
                     }'

get payload(){
return this._myPayload;
}

set payload(value){
this._myPayload = value;
}
```

Let say that during my program run I would like to get 'myPayload' variable many times with current 'valueThatChanges'

e.i.

```
valueThatChanges = 111;
payload= await payload;
log.info('payload1:' + payload);
valueThatChanges = 333;
payload= await payload;
log.info('payload2:' + payload);
```

So eventually I would expect that `'payload1'` will be a payload with value `'111'` and `'payload2'`

will be a payload with value `'333'` but unfortunatelly I get `'undefined'`

```
           {
                "rowCounts":{
                        "rowStart":1,
                        "rowLimit":5
                        },
                 "criteria":{
                        "undefined"
                       }
             }
```

Can someone help how to do this to get my payload with current value of '`valueThatChanges'`??

Answer (score 2):

Create a function which will return you a new payload with the passed value:

```
const getPayload = (valueThatChanges: any) => `{
    "rowCounts":{
         "rowStart":1,
         "rowLimit":5
    },
    "criteria":{
         "${valueThatChanges}"
    }
}`;
```

Call it with the value and get payload with the correct value

Answer (score 0):

A string doesn't keep a reference of the variable used to build it, so you cannot update `_myPayload` by changing `valueThatChanges`

And the getter only get the current value of the variable `_myPayload`.

So if you want `_myPayload` to contains the last value of `valueThatChanges`, you can transform your variable into a function to build the string :

```
private _getPayload(){
 return `
 "rowCounts":{
   "rowStart":1,
   "rowLimit":5
   },
  "criteria":{
   "${valueThatChanges}"
  }
  `
}'

get payload(){
  return this._getPayload();
}
```

I want to add also that you are using `await` while calling `payload`, but your getter isn't asynchrone so you don't need to do that